# How to switch website between http and https, to avoid error accessing http while in https?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my website https:, I am accessing an url in an iframe with http, but it is gives an error:

> insecure content

and the page is not displaying completely but only half page.

What can I do to solve this error?

Has someone experienced it before?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: if you're switching to https, then STICK with https. don't jump back and forth.

Comment: @MarcB What's the reason for this?

Comment: simple example: a secure page that uses cookies. you don't want the cookie contents being snoopable, so you use ssl. but then you load an image or some JS file from the unsecured page, and boom.. your cookie is now sent over the unsecured link in the clear. it's like a bank vault having the biggest strongest steel door out front for the customers, and then a simple curtain on the back door to keep the flies out.